# OSError: [WinError 6] when using undetected-chromedriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, undetected-chromedriver

I'm getting this exeption when my (Python) Selenium scraper completes its tasks, I'm usind undetected-chromedriver:

```
Exception ignored in: <function Chrome.__del__ at 0x00000241A36A6700>
    Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Desktop\22.12.06 Vehicle Scrapper\v2\venv\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 769, in __del__
    self.quit()
    File "C:\Users\Desktop\22.12.06 Vehicle Scrapper\v2\venv\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 758, in quit
    time.sleep(0.1)
OSError: [WinError 6] Controlador no válido
```

This does not affect the functinality of the script but I would prefer a clean shutdown in the console.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) to get around that issue, which has an `undetected-chromedriver` mode with better error-handling and other improvements:

First `pip install seleniumbase`, then run this with `python` as a basic example:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.open("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
    try:
        sb.assert_text("OH YEAH, you passed!", "h1", timeout=8.75)
        sb.post_message("Selenium wasn't detected!", duration=2.8)
        sb._print("\n Success! Website did not detect Selenium! ")
    except Exception:
        sb.fail('Selenium was detected!')
```